# Which flag to use in SimpleCursorAdapter?

Tags: android, sqlite, flags, simplecursoradapter, android-cursor

I use `SimpleCursorAdapter` to send data which I read from `database` to `ListView`.

`SimpleCursorAdapter` has 2 flags and one of them is deprecated.

Should I always use `FLAG_CONTENT_OBSERVER`?

Or is it better to use something else instead of `SimpleCursorAdapter`?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/8790659/1300995 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/7252457/1300995

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) on those flags. `FLAG_AUTO_REQUERY` is deprecated because with it Cursor queries are performed often in UI thread. You should try to use CursorLoader instead. [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) can automatically requery and deliver data in a background thread. 
`FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER` is just registering a content observer on a cursor so you c receive notifications on new data.

Comment: CursorLoader instead of SimpleCursorAdapter? can I bind CursorLoader to ListView?

Comment: you can use both Loader and Adapter. Just use adapter.swapCursor() when in loader's callbacks